# taking multiple values from inputText field separated by commas in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am designing an email client system **using JSF Framework**. The UI should be capable of taking multiple recipient address in the same inputText field each of which is separated by commas(,).
How can i achieve this?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to simply parse the recipient address input string get what you want.

Comment: can i assign the value attribute of *inputText* field to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments:

> *can i assign the value attribute of inputText field to an array?*

You could implement a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) for this.

```
@FacesConverter("commaSeparatedFieldConverter")
public class CommaSeparatedFieldConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String[] strings = (String[]) value;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String string : strings) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(",");
            }

            builder.append(string);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.split(",");
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.addresses}" converter="commaSeparatedFieldConverter" />
```

with

```
private String[] addresses;
```